# XOR Cipher using native C

Tags: c, file-handling, xor

I am practicing my C file handling knowledge by coding a program that encrypts-decrypts a file by a given path. The problem is that my program is encrypting the file but never decrypt it.

I will share below a snippet of code of my program hopefully someone can figure out what's wrong with it.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<windows.h>
#include<stdint.h>
#include<stddef.h>
void flush_n(){
    int c = 0;
    while((c = getchar())!= '\n' && c!= EOF);
}
int main(void){
    char path[281];
    puts("Please enter the path of the file you want to encrypt\\decrypt:");
    scanf("%280s",path);
    FILE*fp = fopen(path,"rb+");
    if(fp==NULL){
        fprintf(stderr,"Unable to open the file!\n");
        Sleep(2000);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    fseek(fp,0,SEEK_END);
    size_t size = ftell(fp);
    rewind(fp);
    char*buff = (char*)malloc(size*sizeof(char));
    if(buff==NULL){
        fprintf(stderr,"Unable to allocate memory!\n");
        Sleep(2000);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    const uint32_t KEY = 0x4FC5D4B;
    for(size_t i = 0;i < size; i++)
        buff[i] ^= (char)KEY;
    fwrite(buff,size,sizeof(char),fp);
    fclose(fp);
    free(buff);
    flush_n();
    MessageBoxA(NULL,"The file has been successfully encrypted\\decrypted!","DONE!",MB_OK|MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    puts("Please press any key to close this window...");
    getchar();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: What's it even supposed to do? `^= (char)KEY` is nonsense, that's the same as `^= 0x4B`.

Comment: Please note that your code isn't "native C", since you use Windows-specific functionality.

Comment: what exactly does it do wrong? If you give it file containing "ipsum lorem", what does it turn that into and back again?

Comment: @gbjbaanb it gives the same letter 'K'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You allocate memory for the file contents, and you XOR the contents of that memory with (a small part of) the `KEY`, and then you write the contents of the buffer to the file, overwriting its previous contents. ***But*** nowhere do you actually *read* anything from the file.

You're just ciphering the contents of the uninitialized buffer, so the output will just be random bytes.

Between the `malloc` and the ciphering loop, you need to call `fread` to actually read the data from the file into the buffer.

Comment: You are right, I had to read the file to the buffer then rewind the file to the begining.